# height value not updating correctly on timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval, timing

I have created a progress meter by updating the height of a span element within a timer function (setInterval). The meter will pause on hover, and then continue when it loses focus (un-hover). The problem is that the height drops down a pixel or two when resuming, rather than continuing from the previous height. I cant figure out why this is happening as the value being passed into the timer function is correct. Any ideas?

Here is a [stripped-down demo](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/qJHxj).

The javascript in question is:

```
function runFlipMeter(meter){
//if meter not defined
if(!meter){
    meter = 0;
}

flipMeter = setInterval(function(){

    if(meter === 0){
        //meter at 0
        grow = true;
        $('.cube').toggleClass('flip');
    }
    else if(meter === 100){
        //reached the top, go back up
        grow = false;
        $('.cube').toggleClass('flip');
    }

    //update meter
    $('#flipperTimer span').height(meter + '%');
    //increment meter
    meter = !grow ? meter-1 : meter+1;

}, 50);

}//end runFlipMeter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you run `meter = $('#flipperTimer span').height();` in function `pauseFlipMeter`, you got a `meter` nubmer of `px`, not a number as a percentage.

[See on Codepen](http://codepen.io/chestnutchen/pen/Ceajp)

```
var flipMeter; //defined globally so it can be paused/cleared
var grow = false;

function runFlipMeter(meter) {
    //if meter not defined
    if (!meter) {
        meter = 0;
    }

    flipMeter = setInterval(function() {

        if (meter === 0) {
            //meter at 0
            grow = true;
            $('.cube').toggleClass('flip');
        } else if (meter === 100) {
            //reached the top, go back up
            grow = false;
            $('.cube').toggleClass('flip');
        } else if (meter.toString().indexOf('px') > -1) {
            meter = Math.ceil((parseInt(meter, 10) / $('#flipperTimer').height()) * 100);
        }

        //update meter
        $('#flipperTimer span').height(meter + '%');
        //increment meter
        meter = !grow ? meter - 1 : meter + 1;

    }, 50);

} //end runFlipMeter

function pauseFlipMeter() {
    var meter;
    $('#resultsFlipper').hover(function() {
        //pause the meter
        window.clearInterval(flipMeter);
        meter = $('#flipperTimer span').height();

    }, function() {
        //resume the meter
        runFlipMeter(meter + 'px');
    });
}



runFlipMeter();

pauseFlipMeter();
```